# How to cancel preference dialog closing after positive button click?

Tags: android, dialog

How I can cancel preference dialog closing aftet any button clicked?

I solved to make that my dialog class implemented OnClickListener.

```
public class PassChangeDiglog extends DialogPreference implements
        OnClickListener {
    EditText oldpass, new_pass1, new_pass2;

    public PassChangeDiglog(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.pass_change_diglog);
        setPositiveButtonText("OK");
        setNegativeButtonText(R.string.Cancel);

    }


@Override
protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {
    setTitle(R.string.PassChanging);
    oldpass = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Dlg_old_pass);
    new_pass1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Dlg_NewPass1);
    new_pass2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Dlg_NewPass2);

    super.onBindDialogView(view);
}


    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        switch (arg1) {
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
           boolean needclose;
           ...
           if (needclose)
               arg0.dismiss();
           else{
               //do not close
           }
        }

    };
}
```

I tried to override onDismiss method, but dialog whatever closing.

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("MY","onDismiss");
    //super.onDismiss(dialog);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add other listener `after` your dialog is already showed.

```
    dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(
          new View.OnClickListener()
          {            
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view)
              {
                 // do your magic
              }
          });
```

To make it work with Preference use cast to AlertDialog:
`(AlertDialog)dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)`

Comment: I added a description of the class.
Unfortunately, this method are not available for my class.
I tried from   `this`, from  `this.getDialog()`.

Comment: My app crashes after this line: 
`((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);` or after call any method...

Answer (score 3):

The solution of my question is overriding of showDialog-method.

```
@Override
protected void showDialog(Bundle state) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.showDialog(state);
    ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
            .setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I need.